# Is there a built-in Python Exception for validation of function input?

Tags: python, exception, raise

I have a function which expects a tuple as one of the arguments

```
def func(x,
         t # t should be a tuple of a predefined type (str, bool, str)
         ):
    ...
```

Is there a built-in error which is appropriate for saying that t is not of the correct type, or should I be defining my own?

Comment: Hi! Is there anything that changed? You swapped the accepted answer, is there anything you feel is missing that I can add?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just randomly ran accross this, and I liked the `ValueError` addition / suggestion from the other answer.

Comment: Sure, it's your choice, always! Just wanted to check. Do know that you asked specifically about an exception for *saying that t is not of the correct type*, which `ValueError` would not cover.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the [`TypeError` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) is meant to be used for exactly this case:

> Raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Passing arguments of the wrong type (e.g. passing a `list` when an `int` is expected) should result in a `TypeError`[.]

You may want to look into using [type hinting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), to catch programmers errors that pass in the wrong type early. We check type hints during linting time, for example.

Comment: Thanks! I love the idea of type hinting, but I'm not sure how to actually programatically validate the type hints (basically, this turns Python into a strongly-typed language, n'est pas?). I'm also working on a small project, so I'm not sure the cost of complexity would be offset by benefit.

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner you'd check the hints statically, with an external tool. The hints are not used at runtime.

Comment: Thanks :) Are there any mature type-checkers though?

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner [mypy](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is mature and in production use at Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would typically be indicated by a `TypeError`. Or if the argument is of the correct type but its value is invalid, use a `ValueError`.

In many cases (especially with `TypeError`) you don't have to raise these explicitly, though; they'll just naturally happen when you try to perform an operation that the type doesn't support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TypeError exception.